# Sum of Javascript value if two conditions are met

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is a code that adds the amount if the `CategoryId` is the same and creates a new `line item` per `CategoryId`.

```
self.OriginalLineItems = [
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 15, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 30, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 20, Type: 'TypeB' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 10, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 5, Type: 'TypeB' }]

self.newLineItems = [];

self.OriginalLineItems.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this[o.CategoryId]) {
        this[o.CategoryId] = { CategoryId: o.CategoryId, Amount: 0, Type: o.Type };
        self.newLineItems.push(this[o.CategoryId]);
    }
    this[o.CategoryId].Amount += o.Amount;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Which would result in the array below:

```
self.newLineItems = [{ CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 65, Type: 'TypeA' }, 
                     { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 15, Type: 'TypeA' }]
```

But I want to add a new condition which is Type, How do I get the results below?

```
self.newLineItems = [{ CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 45, Type: 'TypeA' }, 
                     { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 20, Type: 'TypeB' }, 
                     { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 10, Type: 'TypeA' }, 
                     { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 5, Type: 'TypeB' }]
```

I could not find a solution on the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the key (in your loop) for your object like so:

```
const key = JSON.stringify([o.CategoryId, o.Type]);
```

Then replace `this[o.CategoryId]` with `this[key]`. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/FindIndex) and `every()` to do that.

1. In `reduce()` set accumulator to `[]`.
2. Then use `findIndex()` to find the Object in `ac` for which all the keys are same.
3. You need to use `every()` inside `findIndex()` to check if all `keys` which needs to be matched have same value.
4. If `findIndex()` returns `-1` add the item to `ac` otherwise increase `Amount` of item at the `index` found

```js
let array = [
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 15, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 30, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat1', Amount: 20, Type: 'TypeB' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 10, Type: 'TypeA' },
    { CategoryId: 'Cat2', Amount: 5, Type: 'TypeB' }]
function addBy(arr,keys){
  return arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
    let ind = ac.findIndex(x => keys.every(k => x[k] === a[k]));
    ind === -1 ? ac.push(a) : ac[ind].Amount += a.Amount;
    return ac;
  },[])
}
console.log(addBy(array,["CategoryId","Type"]));
```

Comment: I will mark the other one as answer since I actually still needed the code to make a new array but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @klent Its fine. You should mark the best answer.